# IF into a LOOP in GoogleScript about extracting emails

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

About extracting G-mails to a Google spreadsheet, how can I do to include an IF for dismissing specific e-mails by subject? For example: e-mails responses (with "RE:" in subject). I don't want these e-mails in my spreadsheet.

I've tried with a LOOP but it didn't work because LOOP keeps sending all e-mails to my spreadsheet without a previous selection.

Here's the code:

```js
function GetEmails() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MY LABEL");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      var from = message.getFrom()
      var to = message.getTo();
      var subject = message.getSubject();
      var RE = subject.startsWith("RE:")
      if ([RE != "RE:") {
          process1(message);
        } else {
          process2(message)
        }
      }
    }

    function process1(message) {
      var body = message.getPlainBody();
      var subject = message.getSubject();
      var date = message.getDate();
      var from = message.getFrom();
      var url = "GOOGLE SPREADSHEET"
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.appendRow([date, from, subject, body]);
    }

    function process2(message) {
      var body = message.getPlainBody();
      var subject = message.getSubject();
      var date = message.getDate();
      var from = message.getFrom();
      var url = "GOOGLE SPREADSHEET"
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.appendRow([date, from, subject, body]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: rather `if([RE != "RE:"){` use `if(subject.startsWith("RE:"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE is a boolean in your script.

Also DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

You likely meant to do

```js
const url = "GOOGLE SPREADSHEET";
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

function process(message) {
  var subject = message.getSubject();
  if (subject.toUpperCase().startsWith("RE:")) {
    return; // ignore RE
  }
  var body = message.getPlainBody();
  var date = message.getDate();
  var from = message.getFrom();
  sheet.appendRow([date, from, subject, body]);
}

function GetEmails() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MY LABEL");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      process(messages[j]);
    }
  }
}
```